# How to create shadow on left and right side view?

Tags: android, view, gradient, shadow

I want to create shadow(elevation) to a view. I have seen the same kind of  question is asked here but it has no accepted answer yet.

[Android how to create gradient shadow on left and right of view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401334/android-how-to-create-gradient-shadow-on-left-and-right-of-view)

Now I make it alive.

Comment: Have you tried the given answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this with Cardview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp" >

    <!-- put your attributes -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

http://www.zoftino.com/android-view-shadow-effect

**OR**

You can use 9-patch image.

http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking into [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html).

Your desired functionality is built-in.